# Search all WP REST API Posts with angular

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I using angular to display posts with the WP Rest Api. However the search will only filter through the first 99 posts since that is the max. Is there anyway to yield all results?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom endpoint that utilizes a custom query.  Something like this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'search', '/all', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_all_posts',
  ));
});
```

Endpoint: yoursite.com/wp-json/search/all

```
function get_all_posts() {
  $query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) 
  );
  return json_encode( $query );
}
```

Remember to clear the permalinks when registering new endpoints!

Answer (score 0):

Getting posts is capped at 100 per page, but each request returns the header `X-WP-TotalPages` which gives you the number of total pages in your request.

So do a request for the next pages...

```
var url = your-route.example/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100

$http.get(url).
  success(function(response) {
    var pagesNum = response.headers('X-WP-TotalPages')
        for (var i = 2; i <= pagesNum; i++) {
            $http.get(url+'&page='+i)
                .success(function(response){
                    // do something with the next page data
                })
        }
  });
```

...and so on, until you've gone through all the available pages.

Source: [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/)